Debezium - Syntax Error in SQL Statement: FLUSH TABLES test.customer_demo WITH READ LOCK on OceanHost
I am attempting to connect OceanHost's database with the Debezium MySQL Connector, as they share similarities and can be connected through MySQL. Although the connector is created successfully, I encountered an error in the debezium/connect logs.
io.debezium.DebeziumException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your OceanBase version for the right syntax to use near 'FLUSH TABLES `DB`.`TABLE` WITH READ LOCK' at line 1

I tried a different snapshot.locking.mode and snapshot.mode configuration in JSON, but it's not helping me.
In my opinion, it's caused by the database version, as OceanHost uses MySQL 5.7 series while Debezium supports the MySQL 8.0 series.
Any Suggestion and Solution?
